# How to calculate voting points in a Q&A website using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the following query

```
SELECT a.userid, COUNT(a.id) AS count_answers, SUM(v.yes_vote) as total_up_votes, SUM(v.all_vote - v.yes_vote) as total_down_votes, CAST(COUNT(a.id) + SUM(v.yes_vote) * 4 - SUM(v.all_vote) AS SIGNED) AS voting_points
FROM (answers a)
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers_vote_count v ON r.id = v.answer_id
GROUP BY a.userid
ORDER BY count_answers DESC
```

As you can see, I am trying to calculate the points received on answer received.

Points are calculated like -

- 1 point for every answer - COUNT(answers)
- 3 points for every up vote on answer - 3 * SUM(yes_vote)
- (-1) point for every down vote - SUM(all_vote) - SUM(yes_vote)

My trouble is - if an answer does not have a up_vote and down_vote, the points come out to be NULL. The COUNT(answers) part does not work properly.

What am I doing wrong over here?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Since I am doing the `LEFT JOIN` with the voting, that is why the answers, for which no votes are found, turn up as NULL. This can be solved using the CASE WHEN ELSE in SQL query - by using 0 when the total IS NULL.

Comment: Use `IFNULL` then, it is handy ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - Thanks. Will use that.

Answer (score 0):

Store pre-calculated score value in the questions table.